# Finding center of mass of a thin plate of constant density in specific region

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, logarithms, centroid

The region is between $ y= \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $ y= -\frac{1}{1+x^2} , x=0 , x=1$

What I currently have is this:

[image]

The answer is $ \bar {x} = \frac{\ln 4}{\pi} $ but I cannot seem to get that. Was I supposed to have used $\tan^{-1}x$ ? I'm lost.

Comment: I cannot read the written material. Confine attention to the top half. The area is $\frac{\pi}{4}$, since $\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan x+C$. The moment about the $y$-axis is $\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx$. Let $u=1+x^2$. The integral turns out to be $\frac{\ln 2}{2}$, which is $\frac{\ln 4}{4}$, and we are finished.

Comment: How did you get the area to be $ \frac\pi4 $ ??

Comment: the integral for the total mass is not correct, you are mixing $x$ and $u$ variables together. Just use $x$ and integrate $1/(1+x^2)$ via the standard trigonometric substitution.

Comment: It is $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$. An antiderivative is $\arctan x$, and $\arctan 1=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\arctan 0=0$.

Comment: @EWCZ for the total mass integral, would it be $ \frac{2}{1+x^2} $ as in 2 in the numerator, not 1?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I'm not very good about trig/inverse trig and how they come out to an actual radial, but thank you for that :)

Comment: yes, it should, then the total area is $2\arctan 1=\pi/2$ and if you divide $\ln 2$ with this, you get $2\ln 2/\pi=\ln 4/\pi$ - but of course, if you do everything just with the "upper half", the result should be the same

Comment: The result $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}=\arctan x+C$ is often needed, and it is useful to remember it. You probably met it indirectly in the differentiation part of the course, where it was shown that the derivative of $\arctan x$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. If you do not remember it, the substitution $x=\tan\theta$ will get you the integral.

Comment: It seems like I need to refer back to prior chapters to relearn this. I realized that it was the integral of arctanx , but I did not know that it came out to $\pi/4$ . Again, I'm terrible with that. I will find it in the book or I will find something online and memorize it. Thank you all for your help. If any of you know a good resource or some table to find all of these differentiation functions that would also be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, the area bounded by the given curves: $y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ & $y=-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ between $x=0$ & $x=1$, is symmetrical about the x-axis hence the center of mass will lie on the x-axis.

Now, the x-coordinate of the center of mass of the bounded region is given as

$$\bar{x}=\frac{\int x\ dA}{\int dA}=\frac{\int x(ydx)}{\int (ydx)}$$
Setting the value of $y$ & applying proper limits,
$$=\frac{2\int_{0}^{1}x(ydx)}{2\int_{0}^{1}(ydx)}$$$$=\frac{\int_{0}^{1}x\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ dx}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ dx}$$ 
$$=\frac{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\ dx}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ dx}$$$$=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{d(x^2)}{1+x^2}}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ dx}$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{[\ln(1+x^2)]_{0}^{1}}{[\tan^{-1}(x)]_{0}^{1}}$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{[\ln(2)-0]}{[\tan^{-1}(1)-0]}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\ln 2}{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{2\ln 2}{\pi}$$$$\color{red}{\bar x=\frac{\ln 4}{\pi}}$$

Comment: Thank you Harish for the complete answer! Was very nice of you to break down the problem like that, very helpful to me :)